# Android startActivityByResult Crashing App

Tags: android

I am writing a test app where I am trying to pass two int values to a second Activity and  start the second Activity to run a method and return the data to the first activity. Yet every time I try to pass the values to the second Activity the app crashes.

MAIN:

```
package com.exam2preparationcode;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    // MAIN BUTTON onClick
    public void goToIntentOne(View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentForResult.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

}
```

FIRST ACTIVITY:

```
package com.exam2preparationcode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IntentForResult extends Activity {

    TextView txtTop;
    TextView txtReturnedValues;
    Button btnCallActivity2;
    EditText val1;
    EditText val2;
    String int1;
    String int2;
    int valOne;
    int valTwo;
    private final int IPC_ID = (int) (10001 * Math.random());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();

    }

    public void init() {
        setContentView(R.layout.intentforresult);
        txtTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTop);
        txtReturnedValues = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtReturnedValues);
        btnCallActivity2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCallActivity2);
        val1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.int1);
        val2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.int2);

    }
// CALCULATE BUTTON onClick
    public void callForResult() {

        Intent dataToSend = new Intent(IntentForResult.this,
                IntentForResult2.class);
        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();

        try {
            int1 = val1.getText().toString();
            valOne = Integer.parseInt(int1);
            int2 = val2.getText().toString();
            valTwo = Integer.parseInt(int2);

            if (int1.isEmpty()
                    || int2.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "PLEASE ENTER VALUES TO THE FIELD.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {

                dataBundle.putInt("one", valOne);
                dataBundle.putInt("two", valTwo);
                dataToSend.putExtras(dataBundle);
                startActivityForResult(dataToSend, IPC_ID);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == IPC_ID) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            String text = txtReturnedValues.getText().toString();
            int result = extras.getInt("result");

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                txtReturnedValues.append(text + " " + result);
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SOMETHING WENT WRONG.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }// onActivityResult

}
```

SECOND ACTIVITY:

```
package com.exam2preparationcode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IntentForResult2 extends Activity {

    TextView val1;
    TextView val2;
    Button add;
    Button substract;
    Button multiply;
    Button divide;
    int one;
    int two;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intentforresult2);

        val1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recivedInt1);
        val2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recivedInt2);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        substract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubstract);
        multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiple);
        divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);

        Intent recivedData = getIntent();
        Bundle dataBundle = recivedData.getExtras();

        one = dataBundle.getInt("one");
        two = dataBundle.getInt("two");

    }
// ADD BUTTON onClick
    public void addMe(View v) {

        int result = one + two;

        Bundle returnBundle = new Bundle();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

        returnBundle.putInt("result", result);
        returnIntent.putExtras(returnBundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
// SUBSTRACT BUTTON onClick
    public void substractMe(View v) {

        int result = one - two;

        Bundle returnBundle = new Bundle();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

        returnBundle.putInt("result", result);
        returnIntent.putExtras(returnBundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
// MULTIPLY BUTTON onClick
    public void multiplyMe(View v) {

        int result = one * two;

        Bundle returnBundle = new Bundle();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

        returnBundle.putInt("result", result);
        returnIntent.putExtras(returnBundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
// DIVIDE BUTTON onClick
    public void divideMe(View v) {

        double result = one / two;

        Bundle returnBundle = new Bundle();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

        returnBundle.putDouble("result", result);
        returnIntent.putExtras(returnBundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exam2preparationcode"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.exam2preparationcode.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
             android:name="com.exam2preparationcode.IntentForResult"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity
             android:name="com.exam2preparationcode.IntentForResult2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong...

Comment: Thanks sorted it out... bit late and eyes are not working 100%

Comment: Yeah, I see that. I thought that might be the problem but wasn't going to guess without logcat because there could be so many issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first activity, change:

```
public void callForResult()
```

to:

```
public void callForResult(View v)
```

Comment: i was attempt to post this answer ;) but u did it , u forgot to add `View v`